# Geo location find latitude and longitude using google API

Tags: geolocation

I am trying to retrieve the lat long for my geo location using a google api. This api accepts cell tower information. Irrespective of providing all the information I am not getting correct lat long.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Anyone used this API to find lat long? how much accuracy one should expect from the Geo location API of google?

Answer (score 0):

Below I have extended this [sample from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform), to read Lat/Lng:

**JavaScript code**

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
       /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
       {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    // get latitude and longitude
    // --------------------------
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

    // other stuff...
}
```

**And your address field in HTML**

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
         onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
```